# No WiFi MacBook Pro after ElementaryOS install

Tags: wifi, macbook

Just installed Elementary OS on mid-2009 MacBook Pro. During install, the installer displays and connects to my WiFi network, but after install it does not. In addition, no networks show up. There is something funky with the install process in that in connects and then does not connect upon completion.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but you could use a USB wi-fi adapter. Regardless of the method you choose, you want to install the `bcmwl-kernel-source` package from the command line or the AppCenter.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mid 2009 Macbook Pro 5.5 and I just installed today. Use a Ethernet cable and than install the driver from the [appcenter](/questions/tagged/appcenter).