# I can not use my wifi connection although it is connected

Tags: wifi, networking

I just installed Elementary OS to my laptop, it is an Alienware. When I was in the installation process, it asked which wifi it should connect and after confirming password it installed everything perfectly. After installation finished, I logged into the system and I only see Wired connection set by default. When I open "Network" I see Wifi is connected but "never" used. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does your laptop have an Ethernet port (and if so, can you connect to the Internet  via Ethernet)? I'm asking you this because when I first installed elementary OS, I couldn't connect wirelessly. WiFi icon has appeared only after I connected via Ethernet. No idea why.

Comment: @a-tokarev yes, my laptop has Ethernet port. Do i need to do anything else? Or just connect to Ethernet and that's it?

Comment: Open Network Settings panel and connect your laptop via Ethernet cable. After I had done exactly that, Wireless menu item has magically appeared right below the Wired menu item. So if you see Wireless menu item appear, you can switch to it and unplug Ethernet cable.

Comment: @a-tokarev, ok i tried your suggestion but i do not see any Wi-fi suggestion/option yet in my network manager. I will update my post with screenshots. :)

Comment: Is your Ethernet connection active (connected to the working router)?

Comment: Plus, as an option, after plugging in your Ethernet cable, try installing Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source (by executing `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`), as suggested here (https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/no-wifi-macbook-pro-after-elementaryos-install).

Comment: @a-tokarev I also found the same suggestion. But as the system already asked and connected to a WiFi network, I suppose the driver is already installed, no?

Comment: @a-tokarev actually this `bcmwl-kernel-source` package was the problem. I also saw people mentioned about it in some blog posts. I wonder, if it is a necessary driver to install to activate Wi-Fi, why it is not bundled with installation `iso`. Now a days, i wonder how many people have Ethernet cable available at home. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: All these answers are garbage (no offense). None of them worked. I have tried everything. I am starting to believe E Os wont work with a new desktop or WIFI AT ALL... My other linux builds work fine with wifi. Not E Os or unbuntu... About to ditch and get a refund. Ugh...

Comment: I believe something to do with your network card. May I know your config? If I was able to make it work on a 16 years old laptop, you should be able to do for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so as per @a-tokarev mentioned in his last comment, by installing this `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver i solved the issue. So, all the people out their who is struggling with Wi-Fi connection in their `Elementary OS` distro you can follow either steps from below.

**Solution one:**
Go to your `AppCenter`, click `Installed` tab and check for `Drivers` section. There you will find `bcmwl-kernel-source` driver. Click the button `Free` on it's right & it will install necessary drivers to activate your Wi-Fi connection.

**Solution two:**
Go to your `Terminal` and copy/paste below command and press `Enter`

```
$ sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

You have to provide your `sudo` password to install this. I hope this will be helpful enough.