# Wifi is not detected in elementary 5 Juno

Tags: release-juno, elementary-website

I have installed elementary os Juno on my hp 15 notebook. But it doesn't detects wifi adaptor. It is hard blocked. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19429/i-can-not-use-my-wifi-connection-although-it-is-connected

Comment: I'm having this problem too in my Acer Aspire VX 15, without luck to unblock.