# Can I create a MacBook install image on a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: system-installation, macbook, microsoft-windows, usb-drive

I have a late 2009 Mac Book Pro that cannot perform a macOS re-install.

Can I create a USB install image on a Windows 10 PC that will then boot and install elementary OS on the MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
The elementary OS installation instructions are available [here](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#installation).
I recommend using [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) to flash the ISO on to the USB.

When you go to boot from the USB, you'll need to press and hold the left *Option* key after the startup chime.
A menu will appear with attached disks to boot from.
Select the USB drive to boot the elementary OS installer.

The Debian Wiki has helpful information for installing on Apple devices [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Apple), including several models of 2009 Macbook Pros.
Macbook Pro models from 2009 have model numbers under *MacbookPro5,x*.
You can also refer to [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16247/no-wifi-macbook-pro-after-elementaryos-install) about fixing WiFi after installing on a MacbookPro5,5.